# Array of Linked Lists in C: initializing and inserting?

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to create an array of linked lists (as pictured) and this is what I've made so far:

[image]

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int main(void) {
    Node* link[5];
    for(int q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
        link[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        link[q] = NULL;
    }
}
```

It's been awhile since I've used linked lists in C, so I've forgotten a lot of the syntax and I'm having trouble visualizing what exactly happens when I code linked lists. If I'm not mistaken, when I call malloc in my code, I'm creating a Node with nothing in it yet?

I want to initialize it to point to NULL. And I did this with

```
link[q] = NULL;
```

Am I right in saying this is what it looks like in memory?

|1| -> NULL

|2| -> NULL

|3| -> NULL

---

My next problem would be inserting data into the linked list.

(Referring to the picture): If I want to insert another element into say the 3rd index of the array ([3]-> d -> NULL)

Would this be correct?

```
Node* newNode = link[3];
newNode->data = 1;
link[3] = newNode;
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The insertion is invalid. There is again a memory leak. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Will edit ASAP :)

Comment: May I ask why a memory leak occurs?

Comment: After calling malloc instead of newNode = link[3]; as it was written you have to write newNode->next = link[3];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This loop

```
Node* link[5];
for(int q = 0; q < 5; q++) {
    link[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    link[q] = NULL;
}
```

results in memory leaks because at first memory is allocated and then the pointers are overwritten with NULL. So the addresses of the allocated memory are lost.

You could just write

```
Node* link[5] = { 0 };
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how nodes can be added to elements of the array of lists. Insetad of the data member `data` of the type `int` I am using the data member `data` of the type `char` for visibility.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node 
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;


int push_front( Node **head, char data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( Node **head )
{
    for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%c ", current->data );
    }
    printf( "%s", "NULL" );
}

void display( Node **set, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        output( set++ );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

#define N   5

int main(void) 
{
    Node * link[N] = { 0 };

    push_front( &link[0], 'b' );
    push_front( &link[0], 'a' );
    push_front( &link[1], 'c' );
    push_front( &link[2], 'd' );

    display( link, sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a b NULL
c NULL
d NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: In your function push_front, why do you do this? [int success = new_node != NULL; ] Would there be an occasion that the new_node would point to NULL (after just allocating space for it? Especially with the purpose of the function being collecting data for it anyway?). And why do we return the value of success? Is a return value required? Wouldn't it be the same to just declare the function as "void"?

Comment: @Katrina The function malloc can fail. You need a way to determine whether a node was successfully added to the list.

Comment: Thank you again! :)

Comment: In his case, he knew the size of `link` which is 5. How would you do it if you do not know the size of the array?

Comment: How can we put to each node a struct?

Comment: @wajaap Declare the function push_front like int push_front( Node **head, struct some_struct *obj ); Structures have the assignment operator. Of course you need to change the definition of Node.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you for your help! Could you please help with what I have done so far in this [link] ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142458/how-can-i-have-structs-in-the-nodes-of-many-lists-in-c)

Comment: How can I display from this code one link at a time? For example, link[0], as it is in the push_front function?

Comment: @wajaap If I have understood correctly you can use the function output.

Comment: I tried but this function displays all the links. And if I change the set, for example: for ( size_t i = 2; i < 4; i++ ), it also displays links 1-2 and not the links 2-3.

Comment: @wajaap I do not understand what you want. You can ask a new question at SO.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow already did that : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203249/how-can-i-display-only-listi-from-the-function)

Comment: How could I delete only one node from such kind of list?

Comment: @wajaap Ask a new question at SO.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701510/how-could-i-delete-only-one-element-from-a-node-from-the-list-i-have] just did so!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood your program, the following statement is not necessary:

link[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

since you need to start from NULL pointers, link[q] = NULL; is just fine.

To insert items in the list you should allocate memory for each item, so it should become something like that:

```
Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode->data = 1;
newNode->next = link[3];
link[3] = newNode;
```

It should work, although I did not test it.

Comment: Thank you! I drew out your insert code and I think after allocating space for newNode, you have to point it to what link[3] was pointing to with newNode = link[3]

Comment: well, if you save the pointer of the allocated memory in newNode, than you need to assign the pointer to link[3] too, but not vice versa. So it should be link[3] = newNode.

Comment: My mistake. I was actually referring to newNode->next = link[3], which I thought was newNode = link[3], at first. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have an array of 5 pointers to nodes, that's `link`. You can set those to point to nothing by just doing:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof link / sizeof *link; ++i)
 link[i] = NULL;
```

here you should not allocate any new storage since you don't want actual nodes, you just want pointers to nodes and you already have them.

Your code first allocates, then immediately overwrites the pointer returned by `malloc()` with `NULL`, effectively losing that memory forever. Not good.

When you want to actually *create* a node, that's when you need to allocate it and link it into the proper list.

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the insight. That means my code to insert should be more like... Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the best thing to do for check something if you didn't sure is to see it - print it.

Second, there is mistake in your code -

```
    link[q] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    link[q] = NULL;
```

here you make a new pointer void* in size of `struct Node` and then you lose him when you save NULL in the variable `Link[i]` you have 2 options:

1. To allocate link and then initialize it with `defualt fields` for example - `data =-1`
2. dont allocate and put `NULL` in everty Node before you initialize

my  advise, go with 2, and only when you need to add new node allocate.