# Declare and Initialize dynamic array of head nodes of linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to know how to declare, allocate and initialize array of Node to null.

```
typedef struct Nodes_Of_List { 
        int data; 
        struct Nodes_Of_List *next;
} Node;

//declare array of head nodes
Node *table;

//ALOCATE memory for "x" x is provided at runtime, number of head nodes
table = malloc(sizeof(Node) * x); 

//Initialize elements to Null value
?? //How to do it
```

Explanation regarding initializing dynamic array of head nodes of linked list to Null requested. Purpose is to make array of linked lists, to make a hashtable.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Do you have a single list, or a list of lists?

Comment: Is a `Node` what you mean by a `head node`? Or do you need another structure such as `typedef struct Head_Node { Node *head; Node *tail; } Head_Node;`? (Note that the 'tags' namespace is separate from the ordinary identifiers namespace, so `struct Head_Node` does not conflict with `Head_Node`.) You define an array of whatever type it is the same way as you define an array of `int` — except you use a different type name. If `x` is a variable rather than a constant, you use `malloc()` to allocate the memory. Using `calloc()` will (de facto if not de jure) initialize the allocated memory to null.

Comment: This link can help you a lot: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320526/array-of-linked-lists-in-c-initializing-and-inserting

If you need more details, please elaborate on the comments(or edit question) so we can help.

Comment: You can initialize with
`table->data = NULL;
table->next = NULL;`

Comment: @Lucas: since the `data` element is an `int`, it would be best not to use `NULL` but just `0` to initialize it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Isn't `Null = 0;` ?

Comment: In C.  I is often `((void *)0)` or equivalent, which can’t be assigned to an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood, you want to declare an array of head nodes. After that, you want to initialize them to NULL:

```
//declare array of head nodes statically
Node * table[x];      // x value provided at runtime
// Or dynamically
Node ** table = (Node **) malloc(sizeof(Node *) * x);
// Or use calloc directly wich will initialize your pointers to 0
Node ** table = (Node **) calloc(x, sizeof(Node *));

// table is an array of pointers. Each pointer references a linked list.
// Now you have just to put NULL value in each element of table
int i;
for(i = 0; i < x; i++) 
    table[i] = 0;
```