# How can I have structs in the nodes of many lists in c?

Tags: c, list, struct

I have this code below and I want the variable data in the struct to contain another struct. For example I want my data to be 3 other variables (source, destination and time) so each node from the list to have 3 different position in it. How can I make it possible?

```
typedef struct Node 
{
 char data;
 struct Node *next;
} Node;

int push_front( Node **head, char data )
{
 Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
 int success = new_node != NULL;

 if ( success )
 {
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
 }

 return success;
}
```

Comment: Just add a member that is a struct. But why would it have to be a nested struct? Just give your struct more members.

Comment: @Cheatah would not that mean that for each new member in my struct, I will take a new node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple ways to do it, you can add members to the node struct (best solution in your case) :

```
typedef struct Node {
    int src, dst, time;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Making your data a struct :

```
struct Data {
    int src, dst, time;
};

typedef struct Node {
    struct Data data; /* can also be a pointer */
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Making a struct inside your struct :

```
typedef struct Node {
    
    struct {
        int src, dst, time;
    } data;

    struct Node *next;
};
```

You can make the data struct anonymous (pedantic ansi will complain)
and access the members like in the first example when they were not encapsulated. It is more useful to do when you have an union inside a struct.

```
typedef struct Node {
    
    struct {
        int src, dst, time;
    };

    struct Node *next;
};
```

Now your function could look like one of these :

```
 int push_front( Node **head, int src, int dst, int time );
 int push_front( Node **head, struct Data data /* can be a pointer */);
 int push_front( Node **head, struct {int src, dst, time;} data );
```

Comment: It was so helpful, thank you for your time! I will try them all to see which way I can handle the best.

Comment: how can I display the list after inserting the nodes?