# How can I display only list[i] from the function?

Tags: c, list, function

I have rewritten this code below and in the main function I am calling the push_front function like this:  push_front( &link[i], rollnumber, src, dst, gentime );
My question is how can I display only link[i], for example link[1]?

```
 int push_front( Node **head, int rollnumber, int src, int dst, double gentime )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->rollnumber=rollnumber;
        new_node->src = src;
        new_node->dst=dst;
        new_node->gentime=gentime;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output( Node **head )
{
    for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        //printf( "%d %d %d %0.1f ",current->rollnumber, current->src, current->dst, current->gentime );
        printf("Roll Number:%2d\t",current->rollnumber);
        printf("src:%2d\t", current->src);
        printf("dest:%2d\t", current->dst);
        printf("gentime:%0.1f\n", current->gentime);
    }
    printf( "%s\n", "NULL" );
}

void display( Node **set, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        output( set++ );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The output I am getting when I display all the lists is down below:

```
Roll Number: 6  src: 1  dest:10 gentime:64.1
Roll Number: 5  src: 1  dest: 4 gentime:51.5
Roll Number: 4  src: 1  dest:17 gentime:38.0
Roll Number: 3  src: 1  dest:20 gentime:25.9
Roll Number: 2  src: 1  dest:15 gentime:13.9
Roll Number: 1  src: 1  dest: 3 gentime:1.6
NULL

Roll Number: 6  src: 2  dest:17 gentime:64.8
Roll Number: 5  src: 2  dest: 6 gentime:52.6
Roll Number: 4  src: 2  dest: 5 gentime:39.5
Roll Number: 3  src: 2  dest:20 gentime:26.0
Roll Number: 2  src: 2  dest:19 gentime:14.0
Roll Number: 1  src: 2  dest: 4 gentime:1.9
NULL
```

...and etc. for all the variables : src

The list[i] is based on the variable: src. So, how can I only print for only src: 1?

Comment: Because of the structure of lists, each node is connected via pointer to the next node, (from head to tail if non-circular) thus they are accessed differently than arrays (eg. array of struct.). The next node then would not be represented by `list[i]`, rather `list = list->next` .

Comment: @ryyker isn't it possible to display only first link from the function I already have?

Comment: Not as is.   The output function will have problems with `for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL; current = current->next )`.  For one, the center expression should check `current->next != NULL` rather than `current!= NULL`.  But then the third expression will also error out when the assignment is made using an uninitialized pointer value `current->next` .  If you want to print only members of head node, then pass head pointer as an argument into a function that simply takes a node pointer, and output the member values

Comment: See edit in answer for example of very simple method to output members of one node.  (without error checking, which you should add if plan to use.)

Comment: in one comment you've used the phrase  'first link', in another you've used 'one list'.  In your original post  'list[i]' is used.  ('list[i]' is array notation, not typically used when working with lists.) If I'm not mistaken they all seem to suggest the same thing.  I.e. that you want to output _one node of a list_.  If that is correct then the most recent edit in my post shows how to do that.  If not please clarify your question.  Keep in mind a 'list' is a collection of  pointers called 'nodes'.  Each node points to one instance of the data contained as well as another node(s).

Comment: If indeed your intent is to output the entire list, then the first part of my post ('display(...)') Illustrates that.

Comment: @ryyker you are right! It was my fault and I just edited my actual question above. I meant to say, that I want to display only link[1], as it is in the push_front function as arguement: push_front( &link[i], rollnumber, src, dst, gentime );.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your prototype to pass the list.  Because you are not changing anything, it does not need to be a pointer to pointer.  Then traverse the list until the  condition meets the criteria:

In pseudo code:   (Assuming you have a `Node *next` member...)

```
void display( Node *set, size_t n )//you do not need size of list here
{                                  //but you can use n to indicate node to output
    Node *temp = set;
    
    if(temp->src == n)//check head node
    {
        output(temp)
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next)//check all remaining nodes in list
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        if(temp->src == n)
        {
            output(temp)
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
```

***EDIT***  to address question in comments about outputting a single node.  Once list is created, `output()` can be called from anywhere that has visibility of the list.

```
void output( Node *h )//
{
    printf("Roll Number:%2d\t",h->rollnumber);
    printf("src:%2d\t", h->src);
    printf("dest:%2d\t", h->dst);
    printf("gentime:%0.1f\n", h->gentime);
}
```

For example, In an example `main()`

```
int main(void)
{
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    memset(head, 0, sizeof *head); //initialize
    push_front(&head, 1, 10, 100, 1.0); //first node
    push_front(&head, 2, 20, 200, 2.0); //first node
    push_front(&head, 3, 30, 200, 2.0);//first node,
    output(head); //outputs 1st node
    head = head->next;//points to 2nd node
    output(head); //outputs 2nd node
    head = head->next;//points to third node
    output(head); //outputs 3rd node.
    ...
```

Note that because your code used a `push_front` method, each new node is placed at the beginning of the list, making each new addition the *first node*.
As mentioned in comment, this would need to be bolstered with error checking before use in a real application.

Aside, do not forget to include some `free()` statements in your code to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: thank you for your time, but still can't figure out how to achive displaying only one list

Comment: After your edit I have not understand how can I display a specific head I want, for example not the first but the third one as first.

Comment: After the third 'push_front()' in the example above you have the head node.. Traverse two nodes to the third one by setting 'head = head->next' twice. Now head is pointing to the third node. Pass it to output.

Comment: @wajaap - see edited last example.