# How could I delete only one element from a node from the list I have?

Tags: c, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list, function-definition

My fuctions for insert and display look like below:

```
int push_front( Node **head, int rollnumber, int src, int dst, double gentime )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->rollnumber=rollnumber;
        new_node->src = src;
        new_node->dst=dst;
        new_node->gentime=gentime;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void output(Node* head)
{
  for (Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
  {
        printf("Roll Number:%2d\t",current->rollnumber);
        printf("src:%2d\t", current->src);
        printf("dest:%2d\t", current->dst);
        printf("gentime:%0.1f\n", current->gentime);
  }
}

void display(Node** set, int i)
{
    output(set[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And also the struct:

```
typedef struct Node 
{
    int rollnumber, src, dst;
    double gentime;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

My output for example only for one list I want is:
(this is list 2 based on variable src, I have src 1-10)

```
link[2]:
Roll Number: 7  src: 2  dest: 6 gentime:78.1
Roll Number: 6  src: 2  dest:17 gentime:64.8
Roll Number: 5  src: 2  dest: 6 gentime:52.6
Roll Number: 4  src: 2  dest: 5 gentime:39.5
Roll Number: 3  src: 2  dest:20 gentime:26.0
Roll Number: 2  src: 2  dest:19 gentime:14.0
Roll Number: 1  src: 2  dest: 4 gentime:1.9
```

How can I delete only one node from the above list, for example the:

```
Roll Number: 1  src: 2  dest: 4 gentime:1.9
```

and moreover, would I be able to do this for which link[i] I want without having problem with the whole list?
Can anyone please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: By which criteria are you going to delete a node? By Roll Number?

Comment: Based on my homework, I think that I always have to delete the first line, so the first time it would be rollnumber=1 but the second time it would be the line with rollnumber=2.

Comment: It is unclear whether the lists are sorted. Either you have to delete a node with the specified by the user roll number or just the first node in the list.

Comment: So, isn't it possible to delete the first node in the list?

Comment: It is possible but I am not sure whether you need to delete exactly the first node in the list independent on what roll number it stores instead of deleting a node with a specified roll number.

Comment: No, I do not think that I want a node with a specified roll number. It has to be always the first one, that will be changing when the previous will be deleted.

Comment: Would I be amiss if I assumed that by the "first one", then it's either a heap or a stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly the function can look the following way

```
int remove_node_in_list( Node **set, size_t pos )
{
    int success = set[pos] != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *tmp = set[pos];
        set[pos] = set[pos]->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

This function removes the first node of the list with the index `pos` in the array of lists.

Or maybe it is better also to pass the number of elements in the array of lists to check whether the specified position is within the acceptable range of indices for the array.

For example

```
int remove_node_in_list( Node **set, size_t n, size_t pos )
{
    int success = pos < n && set[pos] != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *tmp = set[pos];
        set[pos] = set[pos]->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: So, what should I put as variable pos when I call the function? I did not understand it well I think.

Comment: @wajaap You have an array of lists with n elements. If you want to remove the first node in the list at the position pos then specify the position of the lists in the array of lists.

Comment: So, when I call the function it would be like that : remove_node_in_list(link, 5); if I want the 5th one?

Comment: @wajaap If you will select the first function definition and want to delete the first node in the list at index 5 in the array of lists then you indeed you need to write   remove_node_in_list(( link, 5 );

Comment: And then in order to display the link without the deleted one should I change something to the display function?

Comment: I tried remove_node_in_list(( link, i); and it does not delete nothing But with: remove_node_in_list(( link, 1);  it always deletes the last node in the list. How is that possible?

Comment: @wajaap No it deletes the first node as you asked. The problem is that you are inserting nodes at the head. So the last inserted node is the first node in the list.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just noticed that. Sorry for that!

Comment: Should I create another pointer in order to insert nodes at the end and not at the head?

Comment: @wajaap It seems you need to add nodes to lists in the sorted order according to the roll number.

Comment: Should I create another function for that?

Comment: @wajaap Either you need to add nodes to lists in the sorted order and you need to rewrite the function that inserts nodes or you need to add new nodes to tails of lists and in this case you also need to rewrite the function or add a new function that appends nodes to tail of lists.

Comment: Very confused now! Isn't it possible to do some changes to the function I already have?

Comment: @wajaap You can change it. But at first you need to decide whether you want to add nodes in the sorted order or to append nodes to tails of lists.

Comment: @wajaap It seems you do not understand yourself what you are trying to achieve.